# Searching Call Logs in Android 10 Dialer app

Tags: phone-app

Had a query-
I've been trying to find out how to search for numbers in the Dialer app (Android 10/Nokia 6.1). It searches only contacts & places.

Eg- Let's say I received a call today from a number say 535-555-5555.

**Since the number isn't saved as a contact**, if I try to dial the number, the number does not show up at all (barring similar numbers from my contacts).

As you start entering the digits, it would narrow down the choices and show you the correct number, when you dialed it (or received a call from). In my previous phone (Vivo /Funtouch OS), this was a very well organized function.

I've tried a few dialer apps but all look only through contacts.

Is there a setting in the native Android 10 dialer app that I can change to allow it to search through call logs? OR Is there a Dialer app in the Play store that can do this?

Sharing links of those who have had similar issues.

https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/7169712?hl=en

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268297/android-how-to-search-through-call-logs-for-a-specific-number

https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s7-edge/698950-how-can-i-search-my-calls-log.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268297/android-how-to-search-through-call-logs-for-a-specific-number

Comment: Hello. It is good that you were finally able to find a solution on your own. That said, because we are a Q&A site and not a forum the correct and the only way to answer here is post your solution as an answer post below. That way, question remains a question and an answer remains an answer, and the format is preserved. :)

Comment: @Firelord, got it.

Found an app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qohlo.ca) that does what I was looking for. However, it feels so strange that one can't search through the Recents in Android 10 native dialer. Shame.